# Delete rows from POSTGRES by timestamp older then days which is a result from SELECT statement from another table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to delete all rows with timestamp value older then the date column from a table in POSTGRES.

To delete rows older then certain timestamp i used this --

`SELECT * from gps_coordinates WHERE sattime < NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY;`

Now i wanted to get the interval time from another table and delete rows based on that. I cant figure out how. I tried this. but it does not work --

`DELETE from gps_coordinates where sattime < NOW() - INTERVAL || (SELECT backup_day as days from gps_devices WHERE id=11) || 'DAY'`

and also this --

`DELETE from gps_coordinates where sattime < NOW() - INTERVAL (SELECT backup_day as days from gps_devices WHERE id=11) || 'DAY'`

this gives ERROR:  syntax error at or near "SELECT"

Help needed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can concatenate and cast:

```
DELETE FROM gps_coordinates
       WHERE sattime < now()
                       - ((SELECT backup_day
                                  FROM gps_devices
                                  WHERE id = 11)
                          || 'day')::interval;
```

The subquery must always return no more than one row though.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you want this:

```
DELETE FROM gps_coordinates 
WHERE sattime < NOW() - INTERVAL '1 day' * (SELECT backup_day FROM gps_devices WHERE id=11);
```

Or with the function `MAKE_INTERVAL()`:

```
DELETE FROM gps_coordinates 
WHERE sattime < NOW() - MAKE_INTERVAL(days => (SELECT backup_day FROM gps_devices WHERE id=11));
```